# Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to login into fresh install mysql with:

```
sudo /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql -u root
```

But getting following error:

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

The mysql server started with:

```
sudo /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld --user=root
```

What is the default login/password for mysql root user?

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**You can reinit the password** :

1.stop mysql

```
/etc/init.d/mysql stop
```

2.start mysql safe :

```
mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &
```

3.connect to mysql

```
mysql -u root
```

4.change the password

```
mysql> use mysql;
mysql> update user set password=PASSWORD(”YOUR_PASSWORD”) where user=’root’;
mysql> flush privileges;
mysql> quit
```

5.stop mysql

```
/etc/init.d/mysql stop
```

6.start mysql

```
/etc/init.d/mysql start
```

Then you can connect to mysql with login root and the new password.

Comment: Trying to use `mysqld_safe` resulted in SOCKET file errors. I was able to fix these by manually making the directory and then giving it to the mysql user. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19119838/3980197). (Mint 18, mysql 5.7)

Comment: What is "mysqld_safe" and where am I supposed to search for one?

Answer (score 1):

There is a subtle issue that needs stating:

```
sudo /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql -u root
sudo /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql -u root -p
```

The first case tries to log in *without* a password.
The second case will prompt you for a password.  At that point you will get a different error message if you don't provide the correct password:

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

Answer (score 0):

Installing MySQL manually by downloading packages for the first time generates a default password for root. Copy and save that. If not done somehow on successive re-installations it does not show that password.

Thus you cannot login to root.
Do the following :

1. Find mysql related entries from system 
   `sudo find / -name mysql`
2. Remove all mysql related entries by doing `rm -rf <mysql_entries_above>`
3. Download latest mysql-server and intall it.
4. You will be promted with a default password which you need to copy.
5. Run `mysql_secure_installation` and paste that password when asked for root.
6. Subsequently follow the steps and change admin password when prompted for.

Answer (score 0):

In the recent version of MySQL running on Ubuntu 18.04, step as below:

1. Find the .conf file, in my case it locate at

`/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.conf`

2. Add under [mysqld]

`skip-grant-tables`

3. Restart the service

`sudo service mysql restart`

4. Connect to mysql

`mysql -u root`

5. Change the password

`mysql> use mysql;
mysql> update user set authentication_string=PASSWORD('YOUR_PASSWORD') where  user='root';
mysql> flush privileges;
mysql> exit;`

6. Restart mysql again

`sudo service mysql restart`

Voila, you can connect now.